# How is it obvious that this question "needs focus"?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I was working through the Close Votes queue today when I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30700131). Although there was an existing vote to close for "needs more focus," I voted to keep it open because:

- It provides a complete, minimal example showing the code the asker wants debugged
- It has a reasonably clear problem statement focused on a single task: He wants to add a second click event that will remove the "extendInputSearch" class from `#searchElement` when a user clicks outside the input element
- It shows the asker's attempt to solve the problem and explains why it didn't work (although this could be better, he just says "it stops my first click event from working" instead of giving more specific error details)

In fact, I can already see the asker's problem and could write an answer that solves it. The problem with his second event listener is that it's being applied to the entire `#main` element (via the variable `offCanvas`), which includes `#searchElement` itself as a child, so when a user clicks on `#searchElement` both the "add class" and "remove class" events get fired and it looks like the first event listener "does nothing."

However, after voting to keep this question open, I was informed that I failed an audit, and the correct answer was to vote to close for "needs more focus." Apparently, it should have been *obvious* that this question was too broad, and could never be answered in its current form. What did I miss in my analysis?

Comment: *"Apparently, it should have been obvious that this question was too broad, and could never be answered in its current form."* - No, audits are procedurally chosen. It being an audit in no way guarantees it should be obvious that it's too broad, indeed it may not be too broad at all. If you think the audit is incorrect, vote to reopen the post from outside the queue.

Comment: Incorrect closure used. Should close vote ban users, since their failed closures result in review bans.

Comment: @TravisJ There's no such thing, unfortunately. At the moment, a close vote ban can only be effected by a complete ban on an all activity, i.e. a suspension. As a result, moderators are, understandably, not inclined to impose such a sanction in any but the most egregious cases.

Comment: If we're talking close-vote bans, then shouldn't we also include up-vote bans? But then we seem to be having the tail wag the dog since one of the main benefits of the site is to allow trusted users to vote as they see fit, even if someone else disagrees with a vote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I assume you mean reopen-votes, instead of up-votes?

Comment: _Although there was an existing vote to close for "needs more focus,"_:  This should have been your clue to decipher what happening under the hood.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - You certainly could have bans on reopen votes. However, with the close votes contained, it would more than likely become obsolete. Improper closure has wide ranging impacts, from incorrectly failed audits, to negative sentiment, to bad messaging, to removal of valid content; improper reopening has a very limited impact and if you look at the total reopening in general, it is extremely rare.

Comment: @DebanjanB - what do you mean "should have been your clue to decipher ..."?

Comment: @davidbak I meant _existing vote to close for "needs more focus"_ should have been the clue

Comment: This is just a poorly procedurally chosen audit. One of the original close vote reviewers agreed with you and [chose "Leave Open."](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30658382) I suggest just accepting that the system is imperfect and move on.

Comment: The review says "duplicate"; which should be a lot easier to check.

Comment: @TravisJ: To make matters worse, the only way to fix a bad close reason is to re-open first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although no one has posted an official answer, it seems like my question has been answered in the comments. According to @Nick:

> No, audits are procedurally chosen. It being an audit in no way guarantees it should be obvious that it's too broad, indeed it may not be too broad at all. If you think the audit is incorrect, vote to reopen the post from outside the queue.

And according to @Ian Campbell:

> This is just a poorly procedurally chosen audit. One of the original close vote reviewers agreed with you and [chose "Leave Open."](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30658382) I suggest just accepting that the system is imperfect and move on.

This makes sense to me, and now that I know more about how the audit system works, I won't be so quick to assume that a failed audit means I'm doing something terribly wrong.

In fact, thanks to the extra attention that particular JavaScript question received from this Meta post, it has now been re-opened and then re-closed as a duplicate of [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893144/javascript-detect-click-event-outside-of-div). This close reason makes a lot more sense, and I would  have agreed with the close vote if I had been shown the other question as a possible duplicate.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/add-an-i-dont-understand-option-for-review-audits